# Extract data from JSON in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I've newly been trying out the Ionic framework. I'm currently trying to make a movie reviews app, using [this](http://developer.nytimes.com/) movie reviews API.

I'm able to retrieve the JSON successfully, but not able to extract the data.

Controller code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
this.http.get('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.json?api-key=a96736504fda41f58b3af1ec5876d3b9')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data.results;
  });
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat = "post in posts">
      {{post.display_title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I get the error

> Cannot read property 'display_title' of undefined.

But there is a field for `display_title`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: initiate `this.posts = []` in constructor, before `this.http.get` operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @CozyAzure says, in this line:

```
{{ post.display_title }}
```

the view is trying to access the `display_title` of something that has not being set yet (since it's being set when the asynchronous method is ready). That's why you get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'display_title' of undefined.

So first, use the elvis operator to let angular know that it should not try to read the `display_title` property if the `post` is null:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor= "let post of posts">
      {{post?.display_title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please notice that the proper sintax of the ngFor loop is

`*ngFor= "let post of posts">`

**and not**

`*ngFor= "let post for posts">`

And also notice that you tried to use AngularJs in your view (`ng-repeat = "post in posts"`) but Ionic 2/3 (or just Ionic) is built on top of Angular, so refer to [these docs](https://angular.io/) to find some more info about how to do things like a for loop.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That is because your data is retrieved asynchronously. When your DOM is loaded, the data has not reached back yet, hence your `posts` is empty, and you will get undefined.

Also, use `*ngFor`:

To solve the problem, use Elvis operator.

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor= "let post of posts">
      {{post?.display_title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Or use an `async` pipe:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor= "let post of posts | async">
      {{post.display_title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Still not working. Its returning an empty list. But the Elvis operator helped remove the error.

Comment: @SauravSircar Check using dev tools if your api is really retrieving the data. If your API is returning empty list, empty list it is. Also, are you using angular1 or angular2? use `ngFor` if its angular2.

Comment: Its not an empty list. When I change "post?.display_title" to just "posts", it gives the output "[object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ..."

Comment: Can you check in the console if the `display_title` is really the property name of the `posts`?